# Javascript d3: Is there a way to programmatically stop dragging an item?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When I'm clicking and dragging an item. Is there a way to forcefully make it stop being draggable without letting go of the mouse button?

For example, if I drag an item across a certain boundary box, can I make it let go of the dragged item?

Comment: I've tried firing a mouseup event just after the mousedown. No luck.
$($0).bind('mousedown', function(){ $(this).mouseup(); })

Comment: if the element is in a bigger container couldn't the drag event be stopped if you leave the bigger container? with $("#selection").mouseleave maybe you could achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/typeofgraphic/Ne8h2/4). I forked a drag example from another user, have added a working boundary in the code. Click to create a circle, then drag it over the blue box to see it working.

The concept here is to observe the x & y coordinates in `d3.event` while an object is being dragged, then trigger the 'stop' event one of two ways as shown below. The drawback is that until the drag event receives a mouseUp, it throws an error while the mouse is still being held down.

```
// Define drag beavior
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", dragmove);

function dragmove(d) {
    // if the event.x goes over a boundry, trigger "dragend"
    if(d3.event.x > 200){

        // using D3 
        drag.dragend(); 

       // or using jquery 
       drag.trigger("dragend");
    }
  var x = d3.event.x;
  var y = d3.event.y;
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
}
```

The boundary here is based on one variable - x location, but can be extended to be based on the surface area of a shape.

Drag is being used as the namespace for this event, an event for which D3 creates a dispatcher object (see the D3 library code). That can be accessed by calling the event name (for example)

```
drag.on("eventName", functionToDo)
drag.eventName();
```

Or if you want to use `JQuery` then a trigger can be applied using:

```
drag.trigger("dragend")
```

Attaching a mouseover event to a 'boundary box' doesn't work as the object being dragged would be between the mouse and the box. Maybe there is a workaround there also. I have included another smaller red box (open the console to see this **not** working).

**sources:**

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals#dispatch_on

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/