# Stop dragmove event programmatically in D3 v5

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js, vuejs2

In a Vue/D3 project, I need to set some restrictions on where some draggable elements may be moved.

This is an excerpt from the `dragmove` handler:

```
dragmove: function(d, i, n) {     
    // Stop if the node crosses a border
    if (parseInt(n[i].getAttribute('x')) > 200) {
        this.drag.dragend(); 
    }
}
```

`this.drag.dragend();` is taken from [an older answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945696/javascript-d3-is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-stop-dragging-an-item). Unfortunately, it does not work in D3 v5 (`this.drag.dragend is not a function`).

This is my `drag` variable:

```
drag: d3.drag()
        .on('drag', this.dragmove)
        .on('end', this.dragended),
```

Is there a way to update my code to work with more recent versions of D3?

Comment: Can you call your `this.dragended` function from within your if-case in the `dragmove` listener function? When trying it, be aware that you need to swap the function to a lambda function or reference `this` outside the function some other way.

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. I can call the `dragended` function, but this doesn't let go the element I grabbed. At the moment I simply return from both the `dragmove` and `dragended` handlers in case my restrictions are violated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `d3.event.on` to temporarily override event listeners. So, to programatically interrupt a drag during the drag event itself, we can use:

```
d3.event.on("drag", null)
d3.event.on("end", null)
```

This temporarily removes the functions assigned to each event listener. 
You'll note I remove the end event too - otherwise it will continue to listen for mouse up regardless of if a function is assigned to the "drag" event listener.

This functionality is described in d3-drag under event.on:

> #### event.on(typenames, [listener])
>
> Equivalent to drag.on, but only applies to the current drag gesture.
>   Before the drag gesture starts, a copy of the current drag event
>   listeners is made. This copy is bound to the current drag gesture and
>   modified by event.on. This is useful for temporary listeners that only
>   receive events for the current drag gesture. ([source](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag#event_on))

In the example below, the drag events are temporarily removed from the circle when it hits the line. A custom event is dispatched to indicate that the drag was programatically interrupted. All events are logged - indicating that end, drag, and interrupt events work as expected:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var drag = d3.drag()
  .on("drag", function() {
    log(); // to log events as they are triggered.
 
    var selection = d3.select(this);
      
    // Update the circle as normal (but don't let cx exceed the line visually):
    selection.attr("cx", d3.event.x > 300 ? 300 : d3.event.x)
      .attr("cy", d3.event.y);
   
      // If event.x > 300, interrupt drag:
    if(d3.event.x > 300) {
      
    // Disable the drag events temporarily
      d3.event.on("drag", null)
      d3.event.on("end", null) 

      // Optionally trigger some alternative event 
      selection.dispatch("interrupted");
    }
 
  })
  .on("end", function() {
    log(); 
  })

var circle = svg.select("circle")
  .call(drag)
  .on("interrupted", function() {
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .attr("fill","orange")
      .attr("cx",250)
      .transition()
      .attr("fill","steelblue");
 
    log();
  }) 
  

function log() {
 console.log(d3.event.type);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 40% !important; }
circle { cursor: pointer ; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300">
 <circle cx="100" cy="50" fill="steelblue" r="10"></circle>
 <line x1="305" x2="305" y1="0" y2="400" stroke-width="1" stroke="black"></line>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to be just what I need - but then I noticed it's possible to move the circle across the border when dragging quickly. So I guess this _should_ work, but some computations are taking too much time (I'm on a 2016 Macbook 12).

Comment: You should be able to stop that, for example, something like: `selection.attr("cx", d3.event.x > 300 ? 300 : d3.event.x)` will ensure cx never exceeds 300 - I'll update the answer, something I should have included.